# Extract face from 3D kinect model

Tags: c++, 3d, kinect

I'm working with a Kinect to create a 3D model of a person. What I get is something like this:

[image: Kinect image]

I export this to a Wavefront .obj file. But I'm only interested in the face itself, and would like to remove everything around it. Since the Kinect has a RGB camera I can do the face detection in RGB without a problem. But that gives me a rectangle inside the 640x480 image containing the face, how do I translate this to the 3D mesh?

Comment: Do you use the point cloud library? Is this kind of what you are looking for: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/ground_based_rgbd_people_detection.php

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar a while back:

[image: Max in depth]

Video [here](https://vimeo.com/36354854)

What I did is fairly simple:

1. Use OpenCV's haar cascade to detect the face in the RGB image
2. Use the detected face rectangle to crop only the face area from the depth image
3. Convert the depth image to depth values (3d point cloud/mesh/etc.)

Ideally you would have the two (rgb,depth) streams calibrated.

I was using libreenect, but this technique should work with OpenNI, KinectSDK.

I noticed the title of your app is KinectFusion so I'm guessing you're starting with the Kinect Fusion sample in the Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.7. There should be a built-in function to align the rgb and depth streams. Regarding the CV part you can find Kinect to OpenCV Mat conversions online, like [Dennis Ippel functions](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/08/01/using-opencv-2-with-kinect-sdk-1-5/) for example. [EgmuCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Face_detection) also has that face detection. And the KinectSDK itself allows you to track the face in 3D, so there must be something in the SDK for Face Detection (not even tracking) I'm suspecting. I haven't used the Kinect SDK enough myself so can't be more specific at the moment.

So in short:

1. detect a face
2. isolate the face region in the depth map
3. convert the depth map face region to a point cloud/mesh/etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, editing the input to calculating the Point cloud might indeed make more sense than trying to edit the output.

But I can't really figure out how to do that quite yet. I'm pretty new to this. I've added some more info beneath.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using to get the Depthstream and process it with Fusion:

```
void processDepth()
{
    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME depthFrame = { 0 };
    ERROR_CHECK( kinect->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame( depthStreamHandle, 0, &depthFrame ) );

    BOOL nearMode = FALSE;
    INuiFrameTexture *frameTexture = 0;
    kinect->NuiImageFrameGetDepthImagePixelFrameTexture( depthStreamHandle, &depthFrame, &nearMode, &frameTexture );

    NUI_LOCKED_RECT depthData = { 0 };

    frameTexture->LockRect( 0, &depthData, 0, 0 );
    if ( depthData.Pitch == 0 ) {
        std::cout << "zero" << std::endl;
    }

    processKinectFusion( (NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL*)depthData.pBits, depthData.size);

    ERROR_CHECK( kinect->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame( depthStreamHandle, &depthFrame ) );
}

void processKinectFusion( const NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL* depthPixel, int depthPixelSize) 
{
    // DepthImagePixel 
    HRESULT hr = ::NuiFusionDepthToDepthFloatFrame( depthPixel, width, height, m_pDepthFloatImage,
                        NUI_FUSION_DEFAULT_MINIMUM_DEPTH, NUI_FUSION_DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_DEPTH, TRUE );
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "::NuiFusionDepthToDepthFloatFrame failed." );
    }

    Matrix4 worldToBGRTransform = { 0.0f };
    worldToBGRTransform.M11 = 256 / 512;
    worldToBGRTransform.M22 = 256 / 384;
    worldToBGRTransform.M33 = 256 / 512;
    worldToBGRTransform.M41 = 0.5f;
    worldToBGRTransform.M42 = 0.5f;
    worldToBGRTransform.M44 = 1.0f;
    Matrix4 worldToCameraTransform;

    m_pVolume->GetCurrentWorldToCameraTransform( &worldToCameraTransform );
    hr = m_pVolume->ProcessFrame( m_pDepthFloatImage, NUI_FUSION_DEFAULT_ALIGN_ITERATION_COUNT,
                                    NUI_FUSION_DEFAULT_INTEGRATION_WEIGHT, &worldToCameraTransform );

    worldToCameraTransform;
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ++trackingErrorCount;
        if ( trackingErrorCount >= 100 ) {
            trackingErrorCount = 0;
            m_pVolume->ResetReconstruction( &IdentityMatrix(), nullptr );
        }

        return;
    }

    // PointCloud
    hr = m_pVolume->CalculatePointCloud( m_pPointCloud, &worldToCameraTransform );
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "CalculatePointCloud failed." );
    }

// PointCloud
    hr = ::NuiFusionShadePointCloud( m_pPointCloud, &worldToCameraTransform,
                                &worldToBGRTransform, m_pShadedSurface, nullptr );


    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "::NuiFusionShadePointCloud failed." );
    }

    INuiFrameTexture * pShadedImageTexture = m_pShadedSurface->pFrameTexture;

    NUI_LOCKED_RECT ShadedLockedRect;
    hr = pShadedImageTexture->LockRect(0, &ShadedLockedRect, nullptr, 0);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "LockRect failed." );
    }

    pShadedImageTexture->UnlockRect(0);
    }
};
```

Now I think the best way is to edit/crop the depthData.pBits. But I'm not sure how to do this.